# How to Wix its worked with Power shell (Power shell script with User input and Prompt)?

Tags: powershell, wix

I want to create Wix Installer to execute many Powershell from Wix and All PowerShell script required User Input. 
Ex.
   Wix application
   Powershell Script: sc1.ps1, sc2.ps1, sc3.ps1, sc4.ps1

All this script required user input like Password, file path, ip address...etc

Want to install all this script By Wix. and manage user input.

Comment: no one is gonna write code here. Sorry to say. You're better off showing code you've tried and the errors you're encountering.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Robert Cotterman.

I've personally never used Wix, never had a reason to. However, getting user input is PowerShell intro stuff, there are plenty of example scripts all over the web as well as in the PowerShell help docs. Use this to get started.

```
Get-Help -Name Read-Host -examples

NAME
    Read-Host

SYNOPSIS
    Reads a line of input from the console.


    Example 1: Save console input to a variable

    PS C:\>$Age = Read-Host "Please enter your age"

    This command displays the string "Please enter your age:" as a prompt. When a value is entered and the Enter key is pressed, the value is stored in
    the $Age variable.
    Example 2: Save console input as a secure string

    PS C:\>$pwd_secure_string = Read-Host "Enter a Password" -AsSecureString

    This command displays the string "Enter a Password:" as a prompt. As a value is being entered, asterisks (*) appear on the console in place of the
    input. When the Enter key is pressed, the value is stored as a SecureString object in the $pwd_secure_string variable.
```

There are other ways to get user input using script parameters vs Read-Host or forms with PowerShell as well, specifically simple PowerShell GUI's using Show-Command cmdlet or full PowerShell apps using WinForms or WPF.